# simple random generator doesn't randomize correct

Tags: javascript

I have created a number generator that ... yes generate random numbers...
The generator works fine every time i reload the page and press the button that give me the random number.

Lets say that the generator give me number 289578 when i press the button the first time.
If i then reload the page. It will give me another random number like 803175.

If I then press the button, without reloading the page it will give me number 803176 
after that it gives me number 803177 once more it give me number 803178.. If I then reload the page it will give me number 8031771 reload  and press button again it give me number 80317711.

So instead of giving an output on 6 different numbers it start adding by one until i reload the page and the it start adding by 1000000. without randomize the numbers.

Any ideas ? I want to keep this as javaScript.. so please no Jquery comments.

Code:

```
var id = Math.floor((Math.random()*1000000)+1);
document.getElementById("add-new").addEventListener("click", function() {
    id += 1;
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's clear what you want to do exactly. In fact I'm sure it's not clear to me.

Comment: @dystroy

Well I want the random number generator randomize numbers. 
But I only randomize once. after that it start adding the generated number with 1... until Its reloading then it start adding by 100000 and not randomize.

Comment: Are you manipulating `id` from somewhere other than the code you posted? What you described makes me think you're trying to add a string to a number.

Comment: If it's doing that after reloading, that means you've got some sort of way of "remembering" the previous session value. You're ending up with a string instead of a number, but it's not clear from what you posted how that happens.

Comment: @Pointy exactly. it was just updating without randomize. 
got i work with the randomness inside the click handler...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your not doing any randomness inside the click handler, all you do is add 1.

Maybe you want just

```
document.getElementById("add-new").addEventListener("click",
    function(){
        id = Math.floor((Math.random()*1000000)+1);
    });
```

Comment: duh! I tried this before i posted a question, but it didn't work... Now its actually working like a charm...
Thank you

Comment: @Dymond So you don't want to add one, but randomize again on every click? We were all thinking you did want to add one after page load...

Comment: @bfavaretto Well on of my nemesis's are to explain problems. :( Ash B did solve my problen though. Thanks!